# Есть ли в Windows сигналы похожие на те что в POSIX?

Tags: c++, winapi, posix

А нет ли в Windows ничего такого, похожего на сигналы в POSIX?

Answer (score 3):

К счастью, в Windows нет ничего похожего на сигналы POSIX. Некоторые авариные ситуации обрабатываются посредством (ранее запатентованных) механизмов Structured Exception Handling (SEH). Например аналогом `SIG_SEGV` будет `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.

Comment: А что предлагается взамен?

Например, моя задача: Нужно аккуратно "прихлопнуть" процесс извне, при этом процесс должен корретно завершиться, выполнив некоторый код.

В Линуске задача решается установка обработчика сигнала SIGTERM и его оправкой процессу соответственно.

Comment: @ksk- Стоит задать отдельный вопрос с подробным описанием. А то получается проблема XY.

Comment: Портированой POSIX либы для видны не существуют?

Comment: @VTT Да, вероятно. Но вопрос скорее общего плана, не только для указанной задачи. На Винде я пока человек новый. Пытаюсь понять, как тут живут люди без привычных мне в Линуксе вещей.

Comment: А либу я такую не нашёл.

Comment: @nick_n_a Частичную реализацию posix интерфейсов действительно можно сделать, но сигналы там будут только номинальные. Ну и большая часть приложений все равно с ними не работает.

Comment: @ksk- На самом деле для такой задачи может быть несколько вариантов решения и в конкретной ситуации некоторые будут более подходящими, чем другие. *"А либу я такую не нашёл."* - то наверное CYGWIN имелся ввиду. А вообще еще есть подсистема Linux.

Comment: @ksk- Еще добавлю, что на linux использованию SIGTERM для прихлопывания процессов приходится делать более толковые (хотя и нестандартные) альтернативы на IPC.

Comment: @VTT Нет, CYGWIN или подсистема Linux меня не устроит. Ровно привязка к компилятору от MS в случае SEH. Инетерсует решение строго в рамках стандарта С++ и системного API.

Comment: @ksk- В рамках С++ ничего нет. SEH - это системное API, но оно явно не предназначено для информирования процессов о том, что они должны завершить работу.

Comment: Что, если у меня компилятор MinGW?

Comment: @ksk- От компилятора задействование SEH никак не зависит.

Comment: @VTT Разве ключевые слова "__try" или "__except" - не расширения языка от MSVC? Или это не то что-то?

Comment: @ksk- Да, расширения. Но SEH на них не завязан.